# How to get the absolute value of a number in Scratch?

Tags: mit-scratch, absolute-value

I want to get the absolute value of a number in Scratch, meaning to drop the negative sign and convert all numbers to positive numbers.

- "-1.5" would become "1.5"
- "-4.56E100" would become "4.56E100"
- "-7" would become "7"

Answer (score 1):

Under the "Operators" code section, I found a block with a built-in `abs` function:

[image: Scratch Abs function]

So you can use it like this to get the absolute value of a number:

[image: Scratch Absolute value of numbers]